MoveIt Inverse Kinematics
I am using MoveIt to control an ABB GoFa, there is a way to get all the inverse kinematics solution given a target pose in cartesian space? I'am using the service GetPositionIK() but it returns just one configuration, to efficiently plan the motion I should have all the IK solution.

Background
Two main different methods for solving IK exist. One method solves the equation analytically. The second uses a simplified version of the IK equation, which is being calculated and evaluated iteratively.
Analytical solvers use trigonometric functions and provide all solutions to meet the specified inverse kinematic requirements.
Iterative methods use the Jacobian matrix and iteratively try to minimize the error between the actual and the desired robot pose.
Implementations:
Analytical:

IKFast

Iterative:

KDL
TracIK (Somehow)
LMA


Example
In order to get all solutions, you need to utilize the IKFast solver, which is robot-dependent and therefore you need to generate the plugin, which takes some time.
After that, change the IK solver to IKFast in kinematics.yaml of your moveit config folder.
By calling
solver->getPositionIK(ik_poses,ik_seed_state, solutions, result, kinematics::KinematicsQueryOptions());

the std::vector<std::vector<double>> solutions; stores your joint states in the form of the vector of calculated solutions.

However,

to efficiently plan the motion I should have all the IK solution

I would not mix the IK task and the planning request.
